# How do I find the dimension and basis of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

If $ 
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$
such that $trace(A)=0$

So it has to be in the form $ 
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & -a \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

How do I find the dimension and basis of this without any further given information?

Comment: Are you asking to find the basis and dimension of the column space of the matrix? A matrix doesn’t have a basis

Comment: @Seeker The space of matrixes with trace zero is a linear space and it has  a basis.

Comment: Look at how many parameters are needed to write the matrix.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah, I was just wondering because I’ve seen other questions asking to find the “basis of a matrix” and often times they mean to find a basis of the column space. Just wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\
 c & -a \\\end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0& 0 \\
 1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So the dimension is $3$ and a basis is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0& 0 \\
 1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, note that $\operatorname{tr} : \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is linear and non zero, so the rank nullity theorem tells us that $\ker \operatorname{tr} = 3$.